# Mirrored object doesn't match it perfectly?

Tags: mirror

Well I retopologized the object and now I am having trouble with the mirror of it. It keeps mirroring int he wrong area and is not matching up equally. Also my verticies at the end of my mesh that would connect the mirror are not alligned properly. Can someonehelp. I have pictures below.[image]

Comment: this is very similar to [How do I make the Mirror Modifier work right](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right)?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the origin of the mesh is not quite in the correct place.

1. Select the vertices that you wish to be the centre of your mirror (the vertical line of vertices which run from the nose all the way
   back around the head and back up to the nose)
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and choose Cursor to Selected.
3. Go into object mode and choose *Origin*> *Origin to 3D cursor* from the Toolshelf (press <kbd>T</kbd> to show the toolshelf).

The mirror modifier should then be moved to be above the subsurf modifier to avoid having a visible seam.

Update: To make the centre line of vertices completely straight, select the centre loop and press <kbd>S</kbd> , <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>0</kbd>.

Comment: But how do I align all the verticies to the same so that my merging isnt so choppy?

Comment: @RayMairlot, you should have said "`S`,`Y`, then `0`", since on the image we can see the mirror is on the Y axis.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I had meant to do that. You could have edited the answer yourself though :)