# Reset object origin without moving object

Tags: objects, transforms

I have been working on this sculpt and noticed when trying to mirror that the point of origin for the model has been moved. How do I reset the location of X and all rotations to zero without moving the object?

[image: mirrored object with origin in wrong spot]

Comment: By the look of it I would say: Shift+S > Cursor to center (if it isn't already) then in Object mode > menu Object > Transform > Origin to 3D cursor. As for rotation: CTRL+A > Rotation

Comment: related, and exhibits close similarity http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right

Comment: ok this might be what some are asking for,i just figured out how to swap my charcater facing position in local so it lines up correctly, after reading all these and many others, all which didn't get it done. in the T menu go to relations, select the part or pieces you want to make local then click MAKE LOCAL in menu choose appropriate selection, if you selected them already, click selected! and Tada ! it all lines up now

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way which assumes your object is centered over 0,0,0:

1. Snap the 3D cursor to the object's origin (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>)
2. Depending on the orientation of your object, set the 3D cursor's location to 0 along one axis (based on your screenshot you'll want to set it to 0 on the Y axis)
3. Snap the origin to the cursor (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>)

[image]

4. Apply rotation (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) to vertices (this will reset object rotation).
   [image]

Comment: Wow. Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C is definitely the worst shortcut I have ever encountered.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg I've never thought it particularly difficult, all the keys are easily within reach of the left hand (on querty anyway). If you prefer, you can click *Set Origin* in *3D view > Tool Shelf* (`T`) *> Tools > Edit*

Comment: I guess it depends on the keyboard and on the size of your hands. It's not a question of reach, but how much you have to twist your fingers. All fingers are forced to leave the home row. I would never be able to do it blind, which defeats the purpose of a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg For blender I typically leave one hand on the modifier keys and one on the mouse; for non-typing tasks like 3D modeling I'm not sure how the home row has much significance (unless you are trying to make some sort of vim-like keymap for somehow keyboard only blendering :P)

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ways you can reset your origin point and both are really easy:

1. Go to object mode, press and hold [Ctrl] [Shift] [Alt] [C] and a menu should appear. Simply select "Set origin to centre" if you want it to appear in the centre of the grid.

If you want it to appear somewhere else, simply click where you want it to be(so the circle and crosshairs appear there) then do the method above but this time, select "Set origins to 3D cursor" and viola! Your origin point has been moved :)

If you find that a bit difficult, here's another method you can try:

2. Go into edit mode, select all of the model by pressing the [A] key, then simply drag your model until the origin point is where you want it to be on the model, then simple go to object mode and move the model back to the centre or wherever you want it(the origin will stay there now.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than moving the origin point of the object, consider using a *Mirror* modifier with an empty axis as the *Mirror Object.*

I've got half of the monkey mesh here, floating somewhere away from the origin and all transformations applied. When I apply the Mirror modifier, it clearly isn't working the way I want it to.

[image: Bad mirror]

To fix this, I'll <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *Empty* > *Plain Axis.* I'll then move it to where I want the mirroring to occur. In this case, I'll just snap it to where I cut the mesh in half.

Then, select the *Plain Axis* as the *Mirror Object*, and change the reflection axis if necessary. Now that your object is mirrored properly, parent the *Empty Axis* to your object and hide it. This will allow you to move your object around now without messing up the mirror modifier.

[image: Final]