# How to fix mirror modifier doing weird things?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror

I had my mesh mirrored correctly at first but then I decided to work on the hand in a different layer (Two) and then copy past it back to layer 1. I then selected both meshes and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to merge the 2 into 1 in object mode. However I forgot to apply the mirror modifier before merging the 2 (not that I thought that would matter) and the mirror modifier disappeared so I go on to connect the hand to the arm in edit mode change back to object mode select all and add another mirror modifier.

Y axis:

[image: Y axis]

Top view of when morring Y axis:

[image]

I've tried all Axis and they all seem to be mirroring weirdly in a diagonal fashion.

#### Things I've tried already

I've selected all vertices that run along the center from top to bottom on the Z axis then Pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and selected "*Cursor To Selected*" followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> selected "*Origin to 3D Cursor*" and still have the same results.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is very likely that you have the object rotated in one or more axis. You can do 2 things (as far as I know):

1. *Apply the rotation* (keeping the current visual orientation): press, while in object mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then select rotation.

   [image]
2. *Set the rotation values to 0* (this will rotate the object to a different orientation): in the object properties menu, in the transform tab set all the rotation values to 0.

   [image]