# Mirror modifier making vertices overlap

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I had a little problem with the mirror because i had he mesh and the mirror mesh were on the wrong side i switched them by applying the mirror and deleting the vertices then i added the modifier again and this happened[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the "clipping" option in the modifier's box?

You also could look into increasing the merge distance.