# mirror not working?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

So I applied the mirror so that i could work on some asymmetrical parts, however, I realized I still need to make some symmetrical adjustments. When I put a new mirror modifier on since the first one diapered when applied i found that the new mirror modifier was not working at all, I don't know if you can put on a modifier already applied but I've tried fixing it so much that I cant undo applying it.

Comment: If you want to apply a new mirror modifier after appying the previous one you have to manually erase the half of the mesh that will be mirrored before, otherwise it will be mirroring over the other existing half of the mesh

Comment: related: [How can I make the mirror modifier work right?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right)

Comment: How do you erase?

Comment: Could you put an screenshot?