# Mirroring a mesh across the origin

Tags: mesh, mirror

I made a path based on a background image, which is the peace sign. Now I've created a path and then turned into a mesh using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Since the sign is symmetrical I'd like to mirror this piece of mesh using the mirror modifier and make a separate mesh, which in turn will be moved along the x-axis. The overall goal is to use the knife project to carve a disk and eventually make the peace sign.

One of you guys here in SE has suggested going into edit mode and selecting vertices. That's not possible in here since the mesh is irregularly shaped from the path.

How can I make a separate mirrored shape?

[image]

[image]

As you can see, Blender is creating one mesh.

Comment: Still not clear... I try: you wish to make an animation that from a circle cuts out with knife project some portions, leaving a "peace" sign in the end?  So you're trying to get "cutting shapes" from the overall shape of the finished sign?

Comment: If your question is about positioning that sign to the left by X axis to make it adjacent to original part, then change Pivot Point for that object. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your object's origin is in the middle of your object. The Mirror Modifier uses the object's origin to mirror from, so you need to do one of two things.

1. Either set the origin of the object to your 3D cursor[image]
2. Or add an Empty to the center of your scene, and select it in the Mirror Object option in the Mirror Modifier to mirror from the Empty's origin
   [image]