# Why is the mirror modifier doing this thing?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

Sorry about the vague title I wasn't actually sure how to ask it. 
So I'm new to blender and am trying to use the mirror modifier. However when I move a vertice in the direction towards the cube (lets say i'm using the default cube) it looks as though i'm removing the skin from a cube shaped banana. There's another cube underneath. I'm not sure if my explanation was any good so i'm also linking a gif in hopes it will aid your understanding of my particular issue.

Thanks for any help x 
[image]

Comment: click on the clipping in modifier panel

Comment: If you want to use a mirror modifier you should have only half a cube, not a whole cube, otherwise it will be duplicating an already symmetric mesh, resulting in overlapping geometry like you have there. Edit your cube and cut it through the middle and remove one half

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right