# Mirror modifier not working?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

Following a tutorial, would like to mirror plane on the other side of her face..

[image: mirror modifier settings]

[image: object not being mirrored]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. It could help if you show where is the origin point of your plane. See also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right

Comment: ^ I believe it is on the intersection point of the x-z axis, should I not be mistaken. (See second picture)

Comment: Did you rotate object in Object mode ? And if yes, did you [apply rotation](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html#apply-object-transformations) after that ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in Object mode you press Ctrl-A and choose Apply Scale and Rotation, then back in edit mode you should be able to get the mirroring across the X axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the button right below the letter V

--------------------------v

[image]

I will circle it in a bit, because I'm on my phone right now