# How can I move the axis of symmetry on a mirror modifier?

Tags: mesh

Sorry for this noob question but i really need help :( xD i want mirror this 
[image]

and it mirrors like this

[image]

its supossed to be a bow so in the middle there are a heart and the other piece has to complete it but it mirrors in reverse?D:

Comment: Move the geometry in edit mode in relation to the object origin. When you do that, do you get the result you want?

Comment: Or dup of this one - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right. Make also sure to press Ctrl+A > Rotation with object selected.