# Getting rid of seam that exists when mirroring after sculpting

Tags: modeling, mesh, mirror, sculpting

Welp, I screwed up. First time seriously sculpting. I sculpted it thinking it would be easy to mirror it afterwards. Now I don't know what to do about the seam, it is very important that I fix this soon. Any ideas? Blend file below

[image]

[BLEND FILE](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=46027)

Comment: Do you have a subdivision modifier on the mesh? if so, make sure it's below the mirror modifier in the stack.

Comment: Can't do that with a sculpt. I solved it just by applying the mirror and tweaking the mesh until the seam is gone.

Comment: FYI, to avoid that, use a symmetry while sculpting instead of a mirror.

Answer (score 2):

You may have internal faces there.
[image]

Select the face and remove it with <kbd>X</kbd>.
[image]
[image]

Also, this answer may be helpful: [How can I make the mirror modifier work right?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right)

Comment: I wish this was the problem, but the model is completely hollow, you can take a look at the .blend file i linked. At this point I'm considering re-sculpting it.