# Mirror modifier: holes in my model and a line down the middle

Tags: mirror

I'm trying to mirror my human mesh but I can not get it to align perfectly. There are holes in the model as well as a protruding line down the face. My mesh shows in edit mode that there isn't any holes or another line down the middle. What do I do?

***And also yes I have selected the line down the middle and put Cursor to Selected and Origin to 3D cursor. It just doesn't look good in the object mode.***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the *Mirror Modifier* is above the *Subsurf one*. Also check out this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right

Comment: Thank you so much! However now are you saying I can't add my Multi-res. modifier until I finish what I have to with my mirror modifier?

Comment: You *can* add Mirror modifier below the Subsurf, it just will mean that first you'll smooth out the half of the model and then mirror it. But as in your case you have Multires, you can't put any modifier above it. Holes with Mirror mean not all the vertices are placed on the mirror plane, some are either overlapping or not touching it, just like in linked answer.