# Making a 3D semicircle and then hollowing out a portion of it

Tags: modeling

I would like to make a 3D semicircle, and then hollow out a portion of the middle, making a shape similar to a letter "D". I need to first make this shape, and then hollow it out. However if there is a better way to do this please tell me.

3D semicircle shape
[image]

Hollowed out portion
[image]

Thank you for any help

Comment: Add a text object "D" then convert to mesh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think hollowing it out is the advised way to proceed, booleans should be avoided.

Just start out with a flat mesh in the shape of the straight part of the D. Make sure it only half of it with the object center correctly positioned so we can symitrize it later

Dividide it at the desired proportions, or extrude a lower part corresponding to the desired letter width.

Correctly place your 3D cursor at the center of the shape and use the *Spin* operator to create half the desired curvature.

Then just let modifiers do the work for you dynamically. Add both a *Mirror* and a *Solidify* modifier to add thickness.

[image]

Comment: You answered this quicker than I could write a _what have you tried so far_ comment.

Comment: Hehe. Indeed very poor question, but I was bored with my current work, needed to unwind a bit :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm going to try this and let you know if it works. I'm still very new to blender, so if I may ask a dumb question, how did you adjust your view to be birds eye instead of how it has you start out?

Comment: What do you mean, rotate the view point? I think it is thw Middle mouse button by default.

Comment: Yes, rotate the view point. In your answer, at the beginning, it shows it from a birds eye view point, I was wondering how to do that? And unfortunately, I am on a laptop so I don't have a middle mouse button, thank you for your response

Comment: You can customize that to be any other key combination, I don't have the default myself, I changed it to Right Mouse button drag.

Comment: I apologize for asking so many questions, as I'm very new to this, how do you correctly position the object center? I have my object center in the wrong place, which is messing up the mirror

Comment: If you have different question make another post, and before you do make sure to search first, in all likelihood someone has asked it before. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right/354#354

Comment: Perfect, sorry for the poorly asked question and all the difficulties, thank you very much

Comment: Welcome, happy blending