# Disappearance of mirrored object?

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, transparency, linked-data

i lost half part of my character which was mirrored earlier? How can i bring it back?

i have done quite well in modelling of head and arms and some parts of legs too.Yet when i m proceeding with the hands and merging the wrist of the hand with the arm....half part of my character's body is found to be lost
so, how should[image: the image shown is the thing where i got stuck] i proceed further

Comment: You can just add a mirror modifier onto the newly merged object. It's likely that you merged an object with a mirror modifier *into* and object without one. The merged object will have the properties and modifiers of the active object, which is the last one you selected. It will have a lighter outline.

Comment: the origin of the object is not aligned with the axis of symmetry. see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right