# a line between the mirror looks strange, how can i fix this?

Tags: mirror

when I scaled the figure down i noticed that there is a ugly line that divides the character(like between the mirror). When I click on the eye symbol so that it shows just half, it looks good but I when its merged it looks odd. I tried to put the merge limit to zero but that didn't help.

is there any way of correcting this??  I have spent so much time on it that I'm paniking

ps im realy new to blender [image]

Comment: Start by moving the SubSurf Modifier to the bottom of the stack (In general it should be last).

Comment: ok i have done that now. is there any difference if you put your subsurf modifier to the bottom of the stack in the end of the process? or do i have to remake the figure with the modifier in the bottom?

Comment: Don't delay modifiers order change, there's no reason to leave that to the end of modelling (in fact it can actively mess the model sometimes). In this case, half of your model is smoothed, including middle edge loop and hole it surrounds, then the mesh is mirrorred and the mirrorred part is smoothed as well. It is not what you want.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you don't want to CC subsurf prior to a mirror with merge.  Once you get that sorted out...

It looks like your model's midline is not at the same location as its origin, meaning that once you mirror it, the margin doesn't get merged (which is probably what you would want.)

Try changing the origin of the model.  First, in edit mode, select your "midline" verts (the margin, not really midline in your unmodified mesh) and snap your cursor to this.  Then, using the 'n' properties shelf, manually place the Y and Z location of the cursor at 0.  Leave edit mode, select your model, shift-ctrl-alt-c origin to 3D cursor, (then alt-g reset position, not strictly necessary but a good idea.)  Now your model's origin is properly set at the same X location as the actual verts making up its midline.

In situations like this, it's not uncommon to have a midline that isn't totally vertical like it ought to be.  After fixing the origin, consider scaling all of your midline verts to 0 about the center in X axis only.  (Snap cursor to center, pivot point cursor, loop select your verts, s x 0.)