# Mesh doesn't mirror right

Tags: modifiers, mirror

Whenever I try to mirror my model, it overlaps and I can't find out how to fix it. I've tried setting the origin, but that doesn't work.
This is my model:
[image: My Model]

And when I mirror it, this happens:
[image: Mirroring My Model]

When I apply rotation:
[image: Rotation Applied]

Comment: Okay, thanks... Could you tell me which transformations do I apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the rotation values for your object. Your object is rotated 180 degrees in X and 90 degrees in Z

[image]

It was rotated in object mode but the rotation has not been applied.

Apply transformations by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose **Apply Rotation** (but you should really apply Rotation &Scale, so that the scale is applied as well)

Read: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

Comment: I did that, but now it's two of the same models next to each other. The other one's not even flipped.

Comment: You need to adjust the pivot point (the center of your object) so that if falls at the point where you want the axis of simmetry see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right

Comment: @Rawan76 most basic questions have been answered before. You can use the search box at the top to find them.