# Mirror modifier rotates object strangely?

Tags: mirror

Im trying to mirror my object to the X axis, as i marked with orange in the attached picture, but instead the mirror modifier is putting the mirrored object onto the top of the main one.  How can i change this?

[image]

Comment: Is othat origin point visible of the object to be mirrored next to 3D cursor? It looks like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right is related but if origin is already on the desired mirror plane try to apply transforms (Object mode > Ctrl+A)

Comment: i managed to do it by duplicating and reversing, thanks